# Excel column datatype issues using MSADO and Access 2016 Engine driver

Tags: excel, ms-access, visual-c++, ado

I'm having an issue updating empty cells in an Excel spreadsheet using the Microsoft Access 2016 OLE DB driver, which I invoke from MSADO/C++. Updating the field causes a "Type Mismatch" exception.

My understanding of the issue was that the Access OLE DB driver determines the datatype of a column by scanning a number of rows as per the  `TypeGuessRows` setting in the registry at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel`

I've tried different values for this setting, and none made a difference. It seems the driver is scanning all the column's cells, and typing them as `VT_NULL`, rather than `VT_BSTR`. If the column is already populated with values, the problem goes away.

The spreadsheet, which is very simple, looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is update the "Target" column with translations of the cells in "Source".
I create an ADO Recordset as follows:

```
CString m_szSQLStatement = L"SELECT [Sheet1$].[ID], [Sheet1$].[Source], [Sheet1$].[Target] FROM [Sheet1$]";
m_pRecordSet->CursorLocation = adUseServer;
m_pRecordSet->Open((_bstr_t) m_szSQLStatement.GetBuffer(0),_bstr_t( m_szConnectionStr.GetBuffer(0) ),adOpenKeyset,adLockOptimistic,
   adCmdText);
_bstr_t bstrFieldName = _bstr_t(L"Target");
FieldPtr pField = m_pRecordSet->Fields->GetItem(bstrFieldName);
pField->Value = "new value"
```

I've tried a few different things to workaround this issue:

- Calling `pField->Value.ChangeType(VT_BSTR)`
- Initializing the  column value with an empty `_bstr_t` like this:
  `pFields->GetItem(bstrFieldName)->Value = (_bstr_t)L""`
- Explicitly casting the column to a string within my SQL query using
  the  `CStr()` function provided by MS-Access.
- Modifying the schema of the document before retrieving data from it
  using `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN "Target" VARCHAR(65535)` - this returned an error saying "operation not supported"
- Adding `IMEX=1` to my connection string's `Extended Properties`
  field - this rendered the spreadsheet read only
- Setting `TypeGuessRows` to 0 in the registry as mentioned previously.

None of the above worked, and I'm now out of ideas. I'm not sure if it's even possible to do what I want with my spreadsheet, but was hoping someone with more knowledge could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Does this help https://onexception.dev/news/1191798/type-mismatch-error-in-excel-updates-with-c-msado

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't think it applies here because if I've understood it correctly, it describes how to assign an empty string to a cell, whereas I want to assign a non-empty string to an empty cell.